# Не срабатывает display: inline; не могу выровнять меню по горизонтали

Tags: html, css

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: cursive;
    background:url(b58a6a0c318d4abfb5a1455bfa726bbb.jpg);
    height: 2000px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1{
    z-index: 1;
    color: aliceblue;
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    top: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
header{
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    left: 40%;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.menu a{
    background: #17181a;
    color: aliceblue;
    padding: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #524d4d;
    border-right: 1px solid #524d4d;
    transition: 0.5s all;
    
    
}

.menu a:hover{
    background: #524d4d;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}


.menulist {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menudrop {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    display: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent; 
    transition: 0.5s opacity;
    border: 10px;
}

.menulist:hover .menudrop{
    opacity: 1;
}
.main{
    z-index: 3;
    height: 1800px;
    background: #17181a;
    margin: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
}
```

Пытаюсь создать выпадающее меню. Использую селектор  `Li` с свойством `display:inline;`

Но, вот  в строку все равно не встает все, ( отдельно без `dropmenu` встает), не могу понять почему.

[image: Что получается на выходе>]

Comment: Покажи HTML......

Comment: Вот, прикрепил код

Comment: У тебя у `header-A` фиксированная ширина

Comment: то что в скобках, я правильно понимаю?                                                                                                   header{
   ( width: 200px;)
    margin: 20px;
    position: fixed;

Comment: Я прекрасно вижу какие стили там прописаны...  Убери `width:200px;`

Comment: Все осталось прежним

Comment: Если у родителя фиксированная ширина и все inline элементы в него в не помещаются по ширине, то они переносятся на следующую строчку. Вы еще с этим столкнетесь на примерах верстки колоночных сайтов. А так да, уберите `width:200px;` и все заработает, если сделаете все правильно.

Comment: Простите меня за мою безграмотность в этом деле) Но убрав ширину, изменилась только немного позиция относительно левого края и усе...

Comment: @ТёмаПопов не стоит извинятся. Дал исправленный ваш пример в ответе, проверьте. Может у вас данные в браузере закешировались и их надо сбросить, хотя не должны по идее.

Answer (score 0):

Если у родителя фиксированная ширина и все inline элементы в него в не помещаются по ширине, то они переносятся на следующую строчку. Я убрал только одну строчку из вашего примера `width:200px;`, элементы верхнего меню встали по горизонтали.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: cursive;
  background: url(b58a6a0c318d4abfb5a1455bfa726bbb.jpg);
  height: 2000px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: aliceblue;
  position: fixed;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

header {
  margin: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}

.menu a {
  background: #17181a;
  color: aliceblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #524d4d;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background: #524d4d;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}

.menulist {
  position: relative;
}

.menudrop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  top: -99999em;
  opacity: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  transition: 0.5s opacity;
}

.menulist:hover .menudrop {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>ШАПОГ</h1>
<header>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li class="menulist"><a href="#">Смотреть</a>
      <ul class="menudrop">
        <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Мультфильмы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Трейлеры</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menulist"><a href="#">Контакты</a>
      <ul class="menudrop">
        <li><a href="" target="_block">VK:Илья</a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_block">VK:Артем</a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_block">VK:Евгений</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
<div class="main">

</div>
```

Comment: а что касаемо выпадающих списков, что нужно поправить?

Comment: @ТёмаПопов в выпадающих списках нужно правильно расставить значения top, left и просто отступы margin/padding. Чтобы было легче, не используйте absolute, используйте relative и почитайте про их отличие. Ну и вместо top: -99999em; обычно устанавливают display: hidden. Попробуйте сделать сами и если не получится, то задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: спасибо большое